# Proving that the gradient of $f$ at $x_{0}$ is equal to the vector where the columns are the partial derivative of the function at $x_{0}$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

I proved the corollary written below, However I couldn't show that $\frac{1}{h}R(x_{0}+he_{i})=o\left(\left|x_{0}+he_{i}\right|\right)$, I wrote (Complete) to the place I should have proven it. Can someone give me a clue? I always get stuck at showing this in most of the proofs. Every feedback will be appreciated. And if there is a problem in my proof I would really appreciate if someone can point it out and explain what is the problem with what I did, thanks!

Corollary. $Let G\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  and $f:G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
 . If $f$
  is differentiable at $x_{0}$
  then all the partial derivatives exists and $\nabla f(x_{0})=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(x_{0}),\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}(x_{0}),...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}(x_{0})\right)$

Proof. Since $f$
  is differentiable at $x_{0}\in G$
 , $\nabla f(x_{0})$
  exists and,$f(x)=f(x_{0})+\left\langle \nabla f(x_{0}),x-x_{0}\right\rangle +R(x)$
 Where $R(x)=o\left(\left|x-x_{0}\right|\right)$
 . We can substitute, $x=x_{0}+he_{i}$
  and get, $f(x_{0}+he_{i})=f(x_{0})+\left\langle \nabla f(x_{0}),he_{i}\right\rangle +R(x_{0}+he_{i})\Rightarrow f(x_{0}+he_{i})-f(x_{0})=h\left\langle \nabla f(x_{0}),e_{i}\right\rangle +\frac{1}{h}R(x_{0}+he_{i})
 \Rightarrow\frac{f(x_{0}+he_{i})-f(x_{0})}{h}=\left\langle \nabla f(x_{0}),e_{i}\right\rangle +\frac{1}{h}R(x_{0}+he_{i})$
 Note that (Complete). Therefore if we take the limit $h\rightarrow0$
  we will get,$\underset{h\rightarrow0}{lim}\frac{f(x_{0}+he_{i})-f(x_{0})}{h}=\left\langle \nabla f(x_{0}),e_{i}\right\rangle =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(x_{0})$
 And therefore $\nabla f(x_{0})=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(x_{0}),\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}(x_{0}),...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}(x_{0})\right)$
 As desired.